# iPad SplitViewController Blank Sidebar After Using Keyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have an iPad app using a SplitViewController interface.  I allow a user to search by tapping in a cell in a TableView in the sidebar.  This brings up the on-screen keyboard:

[image]

After entering the search term the keyboard disappears and leaves an unpainted area in the sidebar TableView:

[image]

I have tried various things (without success) using UIKeyboardWillHideNotification including [self.tableView setNeedsDisplay] and [self.tableView setNeedsLayout].

NB.  The repainting problem only happens the second and subsequent times that a user searches i.e. the first time the sidebar repaints correctly, but after that it paints incorrectly.